# Avoid Android Memory Leak when not using Static Image

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I know this has probably been addressed, however, I am having memory leak issues in my Android app. I have it cycle through a differant picture in the users library every time they push a button. This works fine for the first couple then throws an out of memory exception. I have looked around and though I understood that the pictures are being stored on the heap(?) even after it is not being pointed at. Is there a way I can force this to clean up so I am not getting the error? I have tried the following....

```
private void setImage() throws RemoteException{
    view.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    currentBackground = Drawable.createFromPath(backgroundImageService.getCurrentImageLocation());
    view.setBackgroundDrawable(currentBackground);
}
```

UPDATE:: Update This worked!!!

```
private void setImage() throws RemoteException{
    if(currentBackground != null){
        currentBackground.recycle();
    }
    currentBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(backgroundImageService.getCurrentImageLocation());
    view.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(currentBackground));
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [Bitmap.recycle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29) if you can change your Drawable with Bitmap.